# struts2 program not working

Tags: java, file, configuration, struts2, web.xml

I am new to struts and creating a basic application in struts2. But when i try to run the application, following error occured:
HTTP Status 404 - description The requested resource () is not available

My directory is:
HelloWorldStruts2 folder under webapps folder of tomcat.

in Project folder HelloWorldStruts2:
WEB-INF(folder), HelloWorld.jsp, index.jsp

in WEB-INF folder:
classes(folder), lib(folder),web.xml

in classes folder:
com(folder)->tutorialspoint(folder)->struts2(folder)->HelloWorldAction(class file)
struts.xml

in lib folder: jar files:

index.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1> 
<form action="hello"> 
<label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
 <input type="text" name="name"/> <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.jsp

```xml
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World, <s:property value="name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorldAction.java

```java
package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;
public class HelloWorldAction {
    private String name; 
    public String execute() throws Exception { 
        return "success"; 
        } 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
        } 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        } 
}
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"> 
 <display-name>Struts 2</display-name> 
 <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> </welcome-file-list> 
 <filter> <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> 
 <filter-class> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher </filter-class> 
 </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> </web-app>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd"> 
 <struts> 
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> 
 <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default"> 
 <action name="hello" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" method="execute"> 
 <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result> </action> </package> </struts>
```

please help

Comment: Do you have errors in stacktrace?

Comment: First, please don't use an old version of S2, for a variety of reasons. Second, `struts.xml` should be at the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pack your project into a WAR, do not use exploded folder structure;
2. Use the new Filter, StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter, instead of the deprecated FilterDispatcher;
3. Your DTD in web.xml, it is mixing 2.5 and 3.0 declarations; adjust it to the version supported by your Application Server (that you haven't specified here). Some AS use 2.4, other 2.5, other 3.0.
4. Ensure you have all the needed JARs, all to the latest versions ([2.3.16.3](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi) for Struts, and other versions for OGNL and FREEMARKER). Remove unused JARs if present.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use this filter in your web.xml and remove whatever filter you're using,

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```